# 101 Object not found in Cloud Code - Parse Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm having a strange problem with Parse-Server.

I get **sometimes** the following error:

> ParseError { code: 101, message: 'Object not found.' }

It usually happen after an error in cloud code, in whatever function that use the object even if there is no update in it (like the following function that just doing a find but still create the bug if it fail for any reason like a bad code line). However I'm not sure this is the cause.

I have that simple function in Cloud Code:

```
const user = req.user

const card_id = cid(req, user)
const base_error = global.i18n.__('errors.default')

if(!card_id) return res.error(base_error)

console.log('CID: ' + card_id + ' | UID: ' + user.id)

new Parse.Query(global.m.Card).get(card_id)
.then((card) => {
  if((new Date) - card.updatedAt > OSC.syncDelay)
    return _CARD.sync(card.get('onum'))

  return card
})
.then((card) => {
  res.success(card)
})
.then(null, (error) => {
  if(Array.isArray(error)) error = error[0]

  console.log(error) // HERE is where the error is logged
  res.error(base_error)
})
```

Here is what the console.log print:

> CID: PqOMwi5y60 | UID: QldBflokJV

Here is how the Card ACLs are defined (with an update, not at creation):

```
const cardACL = card.getACL()
cardACL.setReadAccess(user, true)
cardACL.setWriteAccess(user, true)

if(memory.admin) {
  cardACL.setReadAccess(memory.admin, true)
  cardACL.setWriteAccess(memory.admin, true)
}

card.setACL(cardACL)
```

Finally, this is what I have in my Database for the card object Permissions/ACLs:

```
"_id" : "PqOMwi5y60",
"_wperm" : [ 
    "role:Administrator", 
    "QldBflokJV"
],
"_rperm" : [ 
    "role:Administrator", 
    "QldBflokJV"
],
"_acl" : {
    "role:Administrator" : {
        "w" : true,
        "r" : true
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your ACL contains the user (since only the user or admin can read and write from/to the object) in your query you need also to send the session token of the logged in user. So at the end your code should look like the following:

```js
const user = req.user

const card_id = cid(req, user)
const base_error = global.i18n.__('errors.default')

if(!card_id) return res.error(base_error)

console.log('CID: ' + card_id + ' | UID: ' + user.id)

new Parse.Query(global.m.Card).get(card_id,{
  sessionToken: request.user.get("sessionToken") 
})
.then((card) => {
  if((new Date) - card.updatedAt > OSC.syncDelay)
    return _CARD.sync(card.get('onum'))

  return card
})
.then((card) => {
  res.success(card)
})
.then(null, (error) => {
  if(Array.isArray(error)) error = error[0]

  console.log(error) // HERE is where the error is logged
  res.error(base_error)
})
```

Please notice that i sent also the session token in the query.